# Django Rest Framework. What is queryset and serializer_class?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset, drf-queryset

Let's say I have the following viewset:

```
class CategoryViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Category.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CategorySerializer
```

I am wondering what does the **queryset** and **serializer_class** do here? I can assume **queryset** is about how the models' order will be displayed (such as ordering, filtering and so on), but I may be wrong. Please correct me, and, if possible give broad explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**queryset** this to select data from database, you can select all data or apply filter or what you want, in more basic way.. where to write your database query using Django ORM

**serializer** where the queryset will serialize like convert it to json object to use it in response for example, because some ORM query will return QuerySet not a json object

this a basic explained for both, you can check for more details in [Django RestFramework Serializer](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/)